# adding value to dict using keys list

Tags: python, python-2.7

Consider the scenario in which list contains key of a dict

```
x = {'a':{'b': 1}}
lst = ['a','c']
value = {'d': 3}
```

Using the keys present in the list `lst` is there a way to add an entry in the dict `x` .

**Expected Result:**

```
x = {'a': {'c': {'d': 3}, 'b': 1}}
```

Comment: what you have tried?

Comment: An approach could be to access it using `x[lst[0]][lst[1]]` but since the lst can be of any size, im still thinking of how to achieve the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a loop an a temporary dictionary_variable:

```
tmp_dict = x
for key in lst[:-1]:
    tmp_dict = tmp_dict[key]
tmp_dict[lst[-1]] = value
print x
```

Notice, that the loop over all keys except the last one, since we need the last key for the assignment operation.

Comment: This works but why does `tmp_dict = x` does not create a different copy of x ?

Comment: This is how Python handles objects. It only copys a reference to the dict object. Just look at this example: `a = [], b=a, b.append(1), print(a)` (with newlines instead of `,`). If you want to copy something, you have to be explicit and use something like `copy.deepcopy`.

Answer (score 2):

Philipp's answer is good.

But here is my attempt to give you the *exact* answer you expected.

```
x = {'a':{'b' : 1}}
lst=['a','c']
value = {'d':3}

x[lst[0]][lst[1]] = value
print(x)
>> {'a': {'c': {'d': 3}, 'b': 1}}
```

Comment: The answer I expect is using the key values from the list , rather than hardcoding the keys

Comment: @user3351750, I edited the code above. i used lst[0] and list[1]. does that answer it?